# My argv[] in main always returns 0 when converted to integer

Tags: c++, cs50

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<ctype.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int key= atoi(*argv); //key=0, no matter what value I give
    cout<<key;
    cout<<"Enter text:";
    char text[100];
    cin>>text;
    int i=0;
    while(text[i]!='\0')
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i]))
            text[i]=(text[i] + key ) %26;
        i+=1;
    } 
    cout<<text;  //some garbage
}
```

Command line arg:

```
 .\"walkthrough week1".exe 2
```

I've done this for the first time, so I don't understand the error. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `*argv` is equal to `argv[0]` which is the program name. Try `argv[1]` instead.

Comment: You should launch the program in your debugger and see the contents of argv for yourself.

Comment: You could have easily done a `printf("%s\n", *argv);` to see what it is you're trying to convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argv` is a pointer to `char *` which holds the arguments of the program.

`*argv` is equal to `argv[0]` which is the first argument, the program name. You actually want the argument `argv[1]` to be passed to `atoi`, but you should also check if the argument was passed:

```
if(argc != 2)
{
    //print usage
    return 0;
}

int key = atoi(argv[1]);
```

It is also worth to mention that it would be better to use `strtol` instead of `atoi` since it has better error handling.